# 2 proportions hypothesis testing in R

Tags: r, hypothesis-test

I am trying to do a hypothesis test to see if one proportion is significantly different from another proportion. Is there a function in R for this specific situation? How should I get the z-score, Zc, p hat etc. ?

many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I have found r doesn't give you a z-score for 2-proportion z tests, it always uses a X2 test statistic. This gives you the same p-value, however.

You can perform a regular chi-square test or you can use the function prop.test. For this you just create a frequency table of your data and then use that as your "x".

Here is an example:

```
col1 <- c("m", "f", "f", "f", "m", "m", "m", "f")
col2 <- c("p", "f", "p", "f", "f", "f", "p", "f")

array <- cbind(col1, col2)

freqtable <- table(array[,1], array[,2], dnn =c("Gender","Pass/Fail"))

test <- prop.test(freqtable)
print(test)
```

This is the output:

```
    2-sample test for equality of proportions with continuity correction

data:  freqtable
X-squared = 0, df = 1, p-value = 1
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.6481972  1.0000000
sample estimates:
prop 1 prop 2 
  0.75   0.50
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say exactly which test you want to apply without knowing much about the data in question. I find that "rstatix" is becoming very popular for learning how to use R for many common statistical tests. Here is an example from a document where they describe all of the functions. While essentially all are available in base R the test diagnostics can be kind of funky for those not familiar with them.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rstatix/rstatix.pdf

```
 # Exact binomial test
 # Data: 160 mice with cancer including 95 male and 65 female
 # Q1: Does cancer affect more males than females?
binom_test(x = 95, n = 160)

tulip <- c(red = 81, yellow = 50, white = 27)
# Q1: Are the colors equally common?
chisq_test(tulip)
pairwise_chisq_gof_test(tulip)
```

If you supply more information on these data, and what test you are interested, that will help us give more targeted advice. Otherwise check out Rstatix!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that will serve two proportion z test with two-tailed hypothesis

```
twopropztest <- function(p1,n1,p2,n2)
{
p <- (p1*n1 + p2*n2) / (n1+n2)
print(paste0("p :",p))
z <- (p1-p2) / sqrt((p*(1-p))*(1/n1+1/n2))
print(paste0("z score: ",z))

# p-value for two-tailed
print(paste0("p-value(two-tailed): ",(1-pnorm(z))*2))

}
```

If you use `prop.test`, you will need to change `correct = FALSE` and square the X-squared score to get z score. And like what maiebee said, the p value is the same. I have personally verified the z score and p.value of `prop.test`